# T4MVC in MonoDevelop 2.4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, t4, monodevelop, t4mvc

Has anyone tried to make T4MVC work in MonoDevelop?

Out of the box, I get this error: Could not resolve include file 'T4MVC.settings.t4'.

When I include the full path in the include statement, it makes MonoDevelop crash completely.

Thanks for any info!

Marc Lacoursiere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T4MVC relies heavily on the VisualStudio DTE object model, which would not be available in MonoDevelop.  So I don't think you could get it working without changing a lot of things to use an equivalent MonoDevelop API (if there is one).

Comment: I guess you're right... I waisted many hours trying to find out what's wrong with it without success.

Comment: Of course there is a MD API, and it's much nicer than a COM wrapper :)

Answer (score 0):

MD 2.4 didn't resolve included files relative to the files that included them. That might be the problem you're seeing. I've fixed the issue in MD trunk.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I also have tried to replace the include statement by the whole file with no luck.